Google Cloud Run Jobs Task Parallelism Not Working?
I wanted to learn about cloud run job's task parallelism and , so I created a job and set
number of task =10, and , to each container I am giving 8Gb of Memory and 8cpus's.
I have set task parallelism to "Run as many tasks concurrently as possible".
But, when I run this job, it run's 10 task one after other , not 10 task in parallel.
Why , its not running 10 tasks in parallel.
Cloud run jobs running 10 task one after other
I have file of 1.6 gb,and below is my code, which I am running on cloud run instances,to process file and load data to BQ,  just for testing.
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd


project_id = os.environ.get("PROJECT_ID")
task_index = int(os.environ.get("CLOUD_RUN_TASK_INDEX")) 
nb_task = int(os.environ.get("CLOUD_RUN_TASK_COUNT"))
print(nb_task)

df_original=pd.read_csv("gs://dataproc-input-321/train.csv")
df_len=len(df_original)
print(df_len)


batch_size=df_len//nb_task
print("--------------batch--------------")
print(batch_size)
# print("batch size {}".format(str(batch_size)))
print(f"batch size, {batch_size}!")


start_row_no = int(batch_size * task_index)
end_row_no   = int(batch_size * (task_index + 1) - 1)


print(f"For task_id {task_index} , start is {start_row_no} and end is {end_row_no}")
df_sliced=df_original.iloc[start_row_no:end_row_no]
del(df_original)


df_sliced["type"]=np.where(df_sliced["PRODUCT_LENGTH"]%2==0,"even","odd")

df_even=df_sliced[df_sliced["type"] == 'even']
df_odd=df_sliced[df_sliced["type"] == 'odd']


df_even.to_gbq('output_dataset.amazon_even', 
                 project_id=project_id,
                 if_exists='append'
                 )
df_odd.to_gbq('output_dataset.amazon_odd', 
                 project_id=project_id,
                 if_exists='append'
                 )

So, I think , 8GB memory and 8 cpu are enough for processing 1.6 GB.
But,why its not running everything in paraller, if each instance is getting 8Gb memory and 8 cpu's.
There is one option to limit the parallilism called "Limit the number of concurrent tasks", but when I try to enter any value greater than 0,it throws error- "Must be no higher than 0 for selected CPU and memory on the region"
I tried to change region ,but its not letting me set parallalism.
Can anyone explain me,

why its not letting me set parallelism manually?
why it's running single single task, 10 times and processing the files, when "Run as many tasks concurrently as possible" is checked?
3.I notices that, when I was giving 32 GB of Memory to each instances, cloud run complains me, it should have at least 4 cpu's for 32 GB of memory, what is this thing.

Thanks in advance.

I tried to set task parallelism manually, but its not letting me set that value greater than 0.
I tried running in different region, but not able to set task parallelism.


Did you check your quota in your region?

I checked every region, but same issue is there?  I just  I came to know that, this parallelism is somehow related to memory and cpu, which we give to each container.  I have total task to be executed =10, memory=4 and cpu=1, it was not allowing to increase parallelism beyond 1. But, when I changed memory=2, cpu=1, with same region, now it was allowing me, to set parallelism upto 2.  So, its related to memory,cpu and no. of Container we will be running.  But,  I am still confused, because ,  there is no clear documentation about it.  I want to set parallelism to 5, what setting I should use?

That's why I spoke about quotas. You have limitations, and i don't know where they come from. Parallelism is pretty simple. You configure your job (2 CPU, 4Gb of memory, for instance). this configuration apply to 1 instance (that load and run your container). Increasing the parallelism increase the number of instance running in the same time. Set 10 in parallelism, you will need (and pay for) 20 CPUs and 40Gbs of memory.
